# Java separate thread processing based on Object's property

Tags: java, multithreading, interface

I have a list of objects (MyObject).  One of the properties on these objects is a "type" string value.  The list objects are used to spawn threads within a thread pool.  How can I process each object differently depending on its type, without creating new objects for each type that extend the base object?

Basic interfaces would work, but require me to implement them in different concrete classes for each object type (there can be many types).  It feels like there is a pattern to solve this in a clean manner, but I'm not finding it... Anyone have any thoughts?

Here's what I'm looking to complete:

```
                List<MyObject> objects = dao.getObjects();                  
                if (objects.size() > 0) {                   
                    for (MyObject obj : objects) {
                            taskExecutor.submit(???);


                    }   
                }
```

Comment: The argument to `ExecutorService#submit()` is a `Callable<T>` which you have to instantiate.  It should examine the message type and perform the appropriate processing.  I'm not sure what the question is.

Comment: it seems the code you posted is irrelevant to the question. Where is "type" defined. BTW, `volatile lock` seems like a very BAD idea. Make it final instead.

Comment: @kiruwka Type is defined within the Message object, sorry for being unclear.  The code is where the task is to be submit, I suppose I could've paired it down some.  I'll look into why the lock is marked as volatile (thanks).

Comment: @Jim I guess I'm trying to decouple my task processor from knowledge of the specific jobs like this:
taskExecutor.submit(new Callable<Object>() {
        
        public Object call() throws Exception {
// trying to avoid this:         if (msg.getType().equals("type1") {
          // do some task
         }
         else if (msg.getType().equals("type2") {
          // do some task
         }
         return null;
        } });

Answer (score 1):

> One of the properties on these objects is a "type" string value

This is your mistake - use an `enum` for your type and use it as a factory for processing.

```
class MyObject {

  Type type;
}

enum Type {

  TypeA {
            @Override
            void process(MyObject o) {
              // Stuff.
            }
          },
  TypeB {
            @Override
            void process(MyObject o) {
              // Stuff.
            }
          };

  abstract void process(MyObject o);

}

public void test(MyObject o) {
  o.type.process(o);
}
```

Comment: This looks like the direction I'm trying to go. I'll give it a shot and see where it leads... Need to figure out how it can lend itself to returning a Callable from the enum.

Answer (score 0):

I might be getting this wrong (sorry, if I do!), but can't a simple map:

```
Map<String, Function<YourObject, Callable<V>>> typeToTask = new HashMap<>();
```

do the job? So per each object type you just provide a factory of closures (tasks)  which you submit to a thread pool. `Function` could be

```
interface Function<I, O>{
     O apply(I object);
}
```

How to add processing jobs:

```
typeToTask.put("objectType1", new Function<YourObject, Callable<V>>(){
     public Callable<V> apply(YourObject yourObject){
          return new Callable<V> () {
              ... do the job for yourObject of type "objectType1" ...
          }
     }
});
```

Then you could iterate the list and submit the jobs like this:

```
for(YourObject yourObject : objects){
    executor.submit(typeToTask.get(yourObject.type).apply(yourObject));
}
```